# SQL - Select names associated with IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble writing an SQL statement to display a table showing names instead of IDs. I have the following 3 tables:

Item table

```
id   price   name   stock
----------------------
1    0.99    Nuts   43
```

Customer table

```
id     name   
----------------------
1000   Bill
```

Purchase Table

```
id     itemID   Quantity   custID
--------------------------------
100    1        1          1000
```

Essentially, I want a table that has the headings: Item Name, Item Price, Purchase Quantity and Customer Name

Comment: This is a basic `JOIN`, perhaps with a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That is what I've seen from the other answers on here, but I can't figure out how it works with 3 tables as most other examples have 2. So I'm unsure how to apply that to my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty basic [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) , you should read the SQL Tutorial about it

```
SELECT i.name,i.price,sum(p.quantity),c.name
FROM Item i
INNER JOIN Purchase p
 ON(i.id = p.itemID)
INNER JOIN Customer c
 ON(c.id = p.custID)
GROUP BY i.name,c.name
```